# Concatenate binary strings obtained from decimal to binary conversion

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, binary-data

I want to place the binary equivalent number for each element side - by side i.e, the final matrix `Concatenated_A` would be of size `m by nbits*n` where `[m,n] = size(A)`;

```
A = [5, 5,  4,  10, 4;
    10, 10, 10, 10, 5;

    ];
```

I did an attempt but the result is wrong. I need help in correctly implementing the concatenation. Thank you

```
[m,n] = size(A);
numbits = 4;
for m = 1:M

Abin = dec2bin(A(m,:),numbits);
for j = 1:size(Abin,1)
Concatenated_A(m,:) = Abin(j,:);
end

end
```

For first row in `A(1,:) = 5, 5,  4,  10, 4` ; its decimal conversion of each element would give a matrix as below.

```
0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
```

Then, how can I do something like this :

`Concatenated_A(1,:) = [0   1   0   1 0   1 0   1 0 1   0   0 1   0   1 0 0 1   0   0]`

The above operation is repeated for every row in `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose the result of `dec2bin` so that the binary representation goes down the columns and then reshape this into the desired shape so that each row is on it's own row. After reshaping, we take the transpose again so that the rows go across the rows again. Also we need to be sure to transpose `A` before we start so that we encode along the rows.

```
out = reshape(dec2bin(A.', numbits).', [], size(A, 1)).'
%   01010101010010100100
%   10101010101010100101
```

Or if you want a logical matrix instead you can compare your character array to the character `'1'`

```
out = reshape(dec2bin(A.', numbits).', [], size(A, 1)).' == '1'
%   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
%   1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: @SrishtiM Oops! I'd missed a transpose! Fixed now.